# GridView Editing ,Deleting ,Updating is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

im taking Some Invoice No form a table to a Dropdownlist, after select the invoice number  i can take all products to the grid view, with additional , price and all,

my problem is i have to click two times to edit the row, but it is not updating, when click edit button in first row in first time , it is not working , but after click on next row,s edit button first row is enabling the edit textboxes, but not updating only empty data on the grid ...

Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8W6Q.gif

in this part im taking the data to grid ..

```
    DataTable DataTbt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter DtaAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    protected void ddlInvoiceNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GetReturnRecords("Invoice No", ddlInvoiceNumber.SelectedValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", String.Format("alert('Error occured : {0}');", ex.Message), true);
        }
        finally
        {
            DataTbt.Clear();
            DataTbt.Dispose();
            DtaAdapter.Dispose();
            Command.Dispose();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }

    private void GetReturnRecords(string searchBy, string searchVal)
    {
        try
        {
            Command = new SqlCommand("SP_SearchPurchasesLines", Connection);
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchVal", searchVal);
            DtaAdapter.SelectCommand = Command;
            DtaAdapter.Fill(DataTbt);
            if (DataTbt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", String.Format("alert('Error occured : {0}');", ex.Message), true);
        }
        finally
        {
            DataTbt.Clear();
            DataTbt.Dispose();
            Command.Dispose();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

data binding to the grid..

```
    private void BindReturnGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            DtaAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_SearchPurchasesLines", Connection);
            DtaAdapter.Fill(DataTbt);
            if (DataTbt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = null;
                GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
        }
        finally
        {
            DataTbt.Clear();
            DataTbt.Dispose();
            DtaAdapter.Dispose();
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

editing updating deleting row from grid...

```
    protected void GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewPurchaseReturn.EditIndex = -1;
        BindReturnGrid();
    }

    protected void GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewPurchaseReturn.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindReturnGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your  `GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowUpdating` and  `GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowDeleting` methods to update the change:

```
protected void GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
   //Your code to delete the records in db        
    BindReturnGrid();
}




protected void GridViewPurchaseReturn_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code to update the records in db
    GridViewPurchaseReturn.EditIndex = -1;
    BindReturnGrid();
}
```

**EDIT:** After you dispose your command and closing the connection, I think your GridView DataSource should be null. To avoid this, I would change the code like this:

```
//DataTable DataTbt = new DataTable();
//SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
//SqlDataAdapter DtaAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

protected void ddlInvoiceNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GetReturnRecords("Invoice No", ddlInvoiceNumber.SelectedValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", String.Format("alert('Error occured : {0}');", ex.Message), true);
    }
    finally
    {
        //DataTbt.Clear();
        //DataTbt.Dispose();
        //DtaAdapter.Dispose();
        //Command.Dispose();
        //Connection.Close();
    }
}

private void GetReturnRecords(string searchBy, string searchVal)
{
    DataTable DataTbt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter DtaAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SP_SearchPurchasesLines", Connection);
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchVal", searchVal);
        using (Connection)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            DtaAdapter.SelectCommand = Command;
            DtaAdapter.Fill(DataTbt);
        }
        if (DataTbt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", String.Format("alert('Error occured : {0}');", ex.Message), true);
    }
    finally
    {
        //DataTbt.Clear();
        //DataTbt.Dispose();
        //Command.Dispose();
        //Connection.Close();
    }
}

private void BindReturnGrid()
{
    try
    {

        DataTable DataTbt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter DtaAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SP_SearchPurchasesLines", Connection);
        using (Connection)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            DtaAdapter.Fill(DataTbt);
        }
        if (DataTbt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = DataTbt;
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataSource = null;
            GridViewPurchaseReturn.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
    }
    finally
    {
        //DataTbt.Clear();
        //DataTbt.Dispose();
        //DtaAdapter.Dispose();
        //Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @afzalulh, but editing part is the problem,,,
i have to click two times to edit the row, but it is not updating, when click edit button in first row in first time , it is not working , but after click on next row,s edit button first row is enabling the edit textboxes,

Comment: I think after closing the connection first time when you rebind the grid, it's datasource is null. I ahve updated my answer, see if it helps!

Comment: still i have same problem .. i can't edit the grid ...

hear is my sample code with sql + sp 

[Source Code Download](http://goo.gl/U0J5Tc)

Comment: Ok, you can download sample project [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0Zm80V0doTlA2NEk/edit?usp=sharing). WebForm4.aspx and WebForm4.aspx.cs are the files you may need to look at (I had to make change in markup also).

Comment: Thank you very much @afzalulh but ,,, the problem , i have to two times ti click on edit to edit the fields, how to add viewstate when current state of the gridview  data bind.

Comment: Did you test the sample project? you have to click only once, and you don't have to do anything with viewstate.I would suggest to replace your markup and code form the sample. When you will find it working, you can replace the code with small blocks your code and see where the issue is.

Comment: -im using your source ,, but,, this is the result ,,

http://s21.postimg.org/mowetgvvb/image.gif

Comment: Are you using complete project from the sample? if not, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the bind gridview method in inside of !ISPostbak on page load event .

see this code

```
page-load ()
{
if(!IsPostback)
{
BindReturnGrid();
}

}
```

Comment: still i have same problem .. i can't edit the grid ...

hear is my sample code with sql + sp 

[Source Code Download](http://goo.gl/U0J5Tc)